# Rank of quadratic matrix form

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Let $p > r$. Suppose I have a $p \times r$ matrix $V$ of rank $r$ and a $p \times p$ positive semi-definite matrix $X$ of rank $q$ where $q < p$. What does this imply about the rank of 
$$ V^T X V?$$

Is this matrix positive definite if $r < q$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ has a rank $q$, we can write $X = L^TL$, where $L \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times p}$. Hence, we have
$$V^TXV = (LV)^T (LV) = Y^TY$$
where $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times r}$. Hence, the rank of the matrix is bounded above by $\min(q,r)$. However, the matrix need not be full-rank, i.e., it needn't be positive definite. For instance, consider the following example.
$$X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \text{ and }V = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$
We then have
$$V^TXV = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
which is clearly not positive definite.

Comment: As a follow up question; suppose $r < q$. In this case, would $V^TXV$ be positive definite if and only if $V$ spanned some subset of the leading $q$ eigenvectors of $X$? This was ultimately the question I wanted answered -- but that was not very clear in my original post.